# Put value of ViewBag in summernote editor

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, summernote, viewbag

I've tried many solutions but nothing is working. This is my code:

````
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PostDescription, new { @id = "summernote" , @class = "form-control" })<script>
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertText',@ViewBag.Discription); </script>```
````

Comment: Your *@ViewBag.Discription* has a value?

Comment: You can try this `@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PostDescription, new { @id = "summernote" , @class = "form-control" })` or direct binding value using `model class` becuse you are using `Strogly type helper`.

Comment: Is the value in your `@ViewBag.Discription` different from `@model.PostDescription`? Ideally, you should pass this value in your `@model.PostDescription`

Comment: @jishansiddique yes . i already showing this value . the problem is i want to add this  viewbag value in SummerNote ,So any one can easily update it.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal , No model.PostDescription is empty and viewbag.Discription have value ,  Basically i want to add Viewbag value in summernote , and bind summerNote with Model .

Comment: Any reason for not binding the value directly using `@model.PostDescription`? You should be able to populate `PostDescription` in your controller and pass it in the view using the model. ViewModel will make things unnecessarily complicated. Anyways what happens when you try to set the value? Did you check [devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<textarea id="summernote">@Viewbag.Discription</textarea>
```

and on script you can just init summernote:

```
$('#summernote').summernote();
```